# Want to round the data

Tags: oracle

My Query is :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((to_date('01-01-2018 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+ (level-1)),'DD-MM-YYYY'),
        TO_CHAR(to_date('01-01-2018 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')      + level,'DD-MM-YYYY') ,      
        to_number(regexp_substr('7000 T', '^\d+'))/(TO_DATE('04-01-2018 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE('01-01-2018 00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
        || regexp_substr('7000 T', '[A-Z]') AS IP_PLAN      
        FROM dual
        CONNECT BY level <= to_date('04-01-2018 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-to_date('01-01-2018 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

**I want IP_PLAN  like: 2333 T**

Comment: Can you show us, what you already tried?

Comment: Have you tried searching?

Comment: [ROUND (number) in the documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROUND-number.html) You already know what you want to do ('round') so looking in the documentation for a function with that name seems like a good starting point.

Comment: I use this also,to_number(regexp_substr('7000 T', '^\d+'))/(TO_DATE('04-01-2018 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE('01-01-2018 00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
        || regexp_substr(ROUND(('7000 T'), '[A-Z]')) AS IP_PLAN_CONSUMPTION ....but not working @Alex Poole

Comment: its return a string you cant use round on it neither to_number as it contains string!!!

Comment: It looks easy..that only round the data...but logic is....it take day difference between start date & end date...its like 3..then & 7000 will be divide in 3 parts. @Alex Poole

Comment: It would be better to edit your question to include the code you tried to run and the actual error it gave you, rather than trying to do that in comments where it's rather hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ROUND(('7000 T'), '[A-Z]')` is trying to round a string value, i.e. the `T` that is extracted from that source string, which doesn't make sense.

You need to round the number you generated just before that:

```
select to_char(to_date('01-01-2018 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + level - 1,
         'DD-MM-YYYY'),
       to_char(to_date('01-01-2018 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + level,
         'DD-MM-YYYY') ,      
       round(
         to_number(regexp_substr('7000 T', '^[[:digit:]]+'))
           / (to_date('04-01-2018 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
               - to_date('01-01-2018 00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
       )
       || regexp_substr('7000 T', '[^[:digit:]]*$') as ip_plan_consumption      
from dual
connect by level <= to_date('04-01-2018 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    - to_date('01-01-2018 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');

TO_CHAR(TO TO_CHAR(TO IP_PLAN_CONSUMPTION                       
---------- ---------- ------------------------------------------
01-01-2018 02-01-2018 2333 T                                    
02-01-2018 03-01-2018 2333 T                                    
03-01-2018 04-01-2018 2333 T
```

so you're doing

```
round(<number extracted by regex> / <difference in days >)
```

which is

```
round(7000 / 3) => round(2333.333...) => 2333
```

and then appending the `T` after wards.

I've changed the regex patterns slightly so it picks up the space ans any characters at the end. That's making some assumptions about possible values in that string though - i.e. that it's always one number followed by one non-numeric section.

---

Incidentally, if you're using fixed dates then it's simpler to use date literals:

```
select to_char(date '2018-01-01' + level - 1, 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
       to_char(date '2018-01-01' + level, 'DD-MM-YYYY') ,      
       round(
         to_number(regexp_substr('7000 T', '^[[:digit:]]+'))
           / (date '2018-01-04' - date '2018-01-01')
       )
       || regexp_substr('7000 T', '[^[:digit:]]*$') as ip_plan_consumption      
from dual
connect by level <= date '2018-01-04' - date '2018-01-01';
```

though I imagine the `7000 T` and the date values are all being passed in as string in your real code so they need to be converted. You could use a CTE to only convert them once though, instead of repeatedly as you loop round.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((to_date('01-01-2018 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+ (level-1)),'DD-MM-YYYY'),
        TO_CHAR(to_date('01-01-2018 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')      + level,'DD-MM-YYYY') ,      
        round(to_number(regexp_substr('7000 T', '^\d+'))/(TO_DATE('04-01-2018 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE('01-01-2018 00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')),0)
         AS IP_PLAN_CONSUMPTION      
        FROM dual
        CONNECT BY level <= to_date('04-01-2018 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-to_date('01-01-2018 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

you have to use T in some other column;